# R ordering by row values ignoring case

Tags: r, sorting

I have a df with a long list of items, some of which start with uppercase, and others lowercase.  I'm finding it difficult to order/sort/arrange in a way that ignores case.

What I have:

```
 #     name    type    subtype    value
 1     Blue    aab     a          1
 2     Color   aaa     b          0
 3     Echo    abc     a          1
 4     ball    gds     b          1
 5     canal   abc     a          0
 6     delta   aab     a          1
```

What I want:

```
 #     name    type    subtype    value
 1     ball    gds     b          1
 2     Blue    aab     a          1
 3     canal   abc     a          0
 4     Color   aaa     b          0
 5     delta   aab     a          1
 6     Echo    abc     a          1
```

I thought this would be pretty trivial, so I'm not sure why I haven't been able to make order, sort, or sort.list work.

Comment: What's wrong with `df[order(df$name),]`? It works for me. Maybe `name` is coded as a factor?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried that isn't working. Case usually doesn't matter for sort order...

Comment: @MikeH. I must have had the formatting incorrect. That works.  It takes forever on 32million rows, but it did work.  I think my brain was just fried from chasing down this issue that popped up. Thank you!

Comment: With that much data, look into `data.table`. It will be much much faster.

Comment: @Gregor I'll look into that!  I gave up last night because I was chasing my tail. My database pull was sorting based on case, so I used Order to fix that. But it turns out that when I follow up with dcast.data.table a short time later, it casts based on case.  Or maybe its using the row numbers since order doesn't update those?  Not really sure.

Comment: Not really sure what you're doing with `dcast`. If that's where your problem is, show that code.